# Pub get failed from unknown source

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using a package in my project called `card_settings` and it unfortunately depends on another package called `flutter_cupertino_settings`. Actually the last one does not support `cupertino_icons v1.0.0` an I need to update icons package.

I've tried to use the forked repository by `jibiel` used to generate the pull request as `flutter_cupertino_settings` package override but I receive an error that I'm not able to solve:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in my_app...                       
Because my_app depends on dependency_overrides from unknown source "flutter_cupertino_settings", version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because my_app depends on dependency_overrides from unknown source "flutter_cupertino_settings", version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

and this is my dependency override

```
card_settings: ^1.14.0

  dependency_overrides:
    flutter_cupertino_settings:
      git:
        url: https://github.com/jibiel/flutter_cupertino_settings.git
        ref: dfb575c82b67ff76d6df240ccda9fefb53596709
```

Answer (score 0):

Just paste this into your pubspec.yaml file:

```
card_settings: ^1.14.0
flutter_cupertino_settings: ^0.3.1
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
```

Comment: I need cupertino_icons 1.0.0, please read my question

Comment: is there a way you can get around it. How mission critical is cupertino_icons for your project? It avoids you from having to create a fork.

Comment: If there are specific Api (Icons) that you need with cupertino, then I would suggest to find another library. Otherwise you will have to fork the libraries that you need, then import them manually into your platform specific projects, and generate method channels, within a custom helper class, which will handle communication between the Dart layer and the native layer.

Comment: The problem is that dependency override should fix my issue because it was created for this situation. The no sense error is that flutter tell me that dependency override is from unknown source. I need to solve this

Comment: Go to the repo and see if this commit still exists. It might have been rolled back. If you do find it then provide a commit id below the repo url.

Comment: If you do not find the commit, then see if any other commits exist for this repo that will fix the issue and use those commit ids, and if none exist then you will need to raise an issue. Cupertino icons is well maintained, so it should not take too long.

Comment: If you really cannot wait, then you will have to rely on a temporary fork. You want to avoid doing this because then you will not be using a framework that gets continual updates